# downloads file in parallel

Tags: command-line, scripts, wget

I have list of url(near about 50k) of images in text file which I want to download.

Is there anyway I can download it in async way using **wget** command or any other way, by reading it from text file.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following would accomplish your purpose, with 'testing' being a text files with a list of URL images:

```
cat testing | xargs -n 1 -P 8 wget -q
```

Works beautifully on my system! You can manipulate the `-P` option as the man pages describe:

```
-P max-procs
  Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0,
  xargs  will  run  as  many processes as possible at a time.  Use the -n option
  with -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done.
```

References:

- [Stack Overflow: Parallel wget in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577615/parallel-wget-in-bash)